# Android Debugger Hanging in Android Studio 1.5 Beta

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I have breakpoint at a global variable `List<>` in a `Fragment` but as soon as my `Fragment` is added my app hangs in debugging mode.
I don't know how to solve this issue.

**Code:**

```
public class Syllabus extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, LoggerDialog.WhenLoggedIn, ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {
private ObservableRecyclerView recyclerView;
private ImageButton imageButton;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private static HttpClient httpClient;
private boolean isLoggedIn = false;
private AllSubjectsAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<SyllabusCourseItem> names;//I have a breakpoint on this variable.
```

Comment: Java has no global variables. Show us the code snippet and where you put the breakpoint.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set breakpoint on the field definition.

To see value of variable put breakpoint in some method eg. `onCreateView` which is called everytime when system need to create the Fragment.

Comment: Actually I was experiencing unexpected removal in my list and i needed to know where that was happening , so how do i do it ?

Comment: Find places when you make method calls on your list and put breakpoints in these places. In Android Studio use alt + F7 to find usages of variable .